# Getting IRequestReplyRouter does not match service contract or no valid method contract error?

Tags: wcf, iis-7, routes

[image]

No matter what I try and do when it comes to WCF Routing I constantly get this error (via WCF Test Client). I cannot then see any Methods within my service(s)?

At first I just assumed it was my code, so I've downloaded almost all examples I could find of WCF + Routing and just ran those as-is. Same error happens!

I've checked the Event Viewer Logs etc to see if there is an error sneaking into there? nothing. I've tried Googling and Searching here for others (as surely i'm not alone) nothing.

Note:

1. I am using IIS7 with AppFabric Installed.
2. I am using .NET 4.0
3. I am using WCF Service Application Template (default in VS2010)
4. I am losing my mind over this one :)

This one has me absolutely lost as to what is going on?

Here's what the WCF Test Client brings back -

[image]

Comment: @Steve is on the right track. I find it easier to have the WcfTestClient point directly at the target service first to get the service contract. Next, use the Edit with SvcConfigEditor option by right-clicking on the Config File node to change the endpoint address to the routing service. Navigate in the editor to the Client>Endpoint>binding_service node in the left pane and edit the Address property in the right pane to the routing service URL. Do File>Save & exit. Say Yes to the reload dialog. To revert to the target service URL, right-click on the Config File node & pick Restore to Default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WCF 4 routing service will not expose the metadata of your "actual" service unless you expose it via a filtered endpoint or on a separate URL. The wcf test client isn't smart enough to figure that out at any rate.

What I would suggest, if you want to test your routing functionality is use something like soapui. You can then use it to modify the service address to which you send your request to.

If you want to expose your service metadata via the router this article should help.

http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework-402/Routing-Service-Metadata/

HTH

Comment: The URL is giving the ASP.NET 404 error when you click it. The site seems to be OK. Typo?

Comment: Steve: I also found an alternative ontop of your answer. In that if I add one of the routed-to services as a "Service Reference" then i can have proxies etc generated inline code, then via the app.config i switch the endpoint back to the routing.svc and it all snaps together.

Comment: @Scott: Cool, glad you found a solution. Will have to try that one myself. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When I got this error it was because I did the contract-first approach and made my own WSDL and then used it to create the interface for the service.

WCF Test Client will dynamically create the WSDL and then the contract name it dynamically assigns did not match the one I manually setup.

Once I changed my web.config to have the `externalMetadataLocation` attribute filled in the `serviceMetadata` element and pointed it to my static WSDL everything was fine.